# How to display vertical items in the card view in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, cross-platform

I'm trying to display items in the card vertically, but in the card content I'm facing an issue that is, "**Bottom overflowed by 52 pixels**".

Here, I'm attaching code, my design's screenshot, and the screenshot of what actually I need.
Please help!

[image: Screenshot of my screen]

[image: screenshot of what I actually want to do]

**Below is my code.**

```
 Widget buildRowItemsGrid(BuildContext context, int index) {
FlutterMoneyFormatter formatter =
    FlutterMoneyFormatter(amount: items[index].price);

return Container(
  child: Card(
    elevation: 5.0,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Image.network(
              "https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/images/q_auto,f_auto/gigs/118898040/original/870e2763755963f5a300574bbea5977fa8b18460/sell-original-football-and-basketball-teams-jersey.jpg",
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              fit: BoxFit.fill),
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Text(items[index].title,
                  style: titleTextStyle,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0),
                  child: Text(items[index].subtitle,
                      style: subtitleTextStyle)),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(formatter.output.symbolOnLeft,
                      style: priceTextStyle),
                  Text("ADD TO CART", style: addToCardTextStyle)
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

**Code of Grid View**

```
Widget buildGridView() {
return Expanded(
  child: GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: List.generate(items.length, (index) {
        return buildRowItemsGrid(context, index);
      })),
);
```

Comment: If your data is limited to this you can set the height of your `Container`

Comment: @AR I checked that too by adding the height of `Container` up to 200, but the same result

Comment: Can you please add your listview code too ?

Comment: please check question again, I have added grid view code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set an appropriate `childAspectRatio` in the `GridView` like this.

```
GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 2/3,     //<-- width/height ratio depending on the child's content. Set accordingly.
        //...
)
```

*Edit:*

The above part will solve the overflow problem. In addition to that, you can make the size of the `Image` widget adaptive like this so it can take up more space when available.

```
Image.network(
                "https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/images/q_auto,f_auto/gigs/118898040/original/870e2763755963f5a300574bbea5977fa8b18460/sell-original-football-and-basketball-teams-jersey.jpg",
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.8,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.8,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              )
```

You can also set the `Column`'s `mainAxisAlignment` to `spaceEvenly` so its children can take up the space evenly when more space is available vertically.

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      //...
)
```

Comment: it is working, but it consumes extra space at the bottom after "ADD TO CART" text.

Comment: Yes, that is why I mentioned that you need to set an "appropriate" value to `childAspectRatio`. 2/3 is only an example value. You don't necessarily need to set it to 2/3 exactly. You can play around with the value to set a suitable value to it. Like you can try 2/2.8, 2/2.7 etc.

Comment: okay, I got it. How it looks like if I put media query here?  because in future anything changes in the size of text or the height of the image.

Comment: @DarshitAnjaria Using MediaQuery to set the `childAspectRatio` for the `GridView` doesn't make sense. Because it gives the device's size and the child aspect ratio need to be set depending on the content of the child. Instead, you can use MediaQuery to set the width and height of the `Image` widget inside the child so it becomes adaptive to the screen size. I'll edit the answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the `ScreenShot`, but from the code I suggest you wrap The Second Column with `Expanded` and then the first column wrap it with `SingleChildScrollView`, that way it won't overflowed and you can scroll through if the contain inside were higher

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a fixed size for your Grid item. So it will overflow if the height of the Grid is not enough.

I have two ideas for you:

1. Use auto_size_text https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

```dart
Expanded(
  child: AutoSizeText(
   'The text to display',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
    maxLines: 2,
    minFontSize: 1,
  ),
)
```

2. Increase the height of your Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work? Have you given it some fixed height in its parents? If given remove that, and then try this.

```
Widget buildRowItemsGrid(BuildContext context, int index) {
FlutterMoneyFormatter formatter =
    FlutterMoneyFormatter(amount: items[index].price);

return Container(
  child: Card(
    elevation: 5.0,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Image.network(
              "https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/images/q_auto,f_auto/gigs/118898040/original/870e2763755963f5a300574bbea5977fa8b18460/sell-original-football-and-basketball-teams-jersey.jpg",
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              fit: BoxFit.fill),
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Text(items[index].title,
                  style: titleTextStyle,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 10.0, 5.0),
                  child: Text(items[index].subtitle,
                      style: subtitleTextStyle)),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(formatter.output.symbolOnLeft,
                      style: priceTextStyle),
                  Text("ADD TO CART", style: addToCardTextStyle)
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the overflowing widget with a Flexible widget. The child of the Flexible widget will fill the available space in the main axis.